# Yellow stains on the ceiling, how to diagnose

Tags: ceiling, roof

Today I just noticed two new yellow stains on the ceiling of my bedroom. They are both size of an apple. I am pretty sure they are not there before.

We have had a lot rain for last a few weeks. I guess I may have water leakage on my roof. Just wondering what I should do now?

Comment: Are you asking how to diagnose a water leak, or how to repair ceiling stains? Please edit your post and your title to ask a more clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to get up into the loft (assuming the bedroom is on the top floor of the house) and look for signs of water up there. You should have insulation of some sort, this will hold the water.

Then check for nearby damage inside and out. Binoculars can help with the latter. You'll probably have to get it professionally repaired but you need to stop things getting worse until that happens. And you may want to get in touch with your insurer.

Comment: Thanks alot...may I ask how to get to the loft? Sorry I am a new home owner and never owned a house before

Comment: House construction varies a lot. I can only really speak for the UK. But logically there should be something similar in most houses with sloping roofs. Look in the upstairs ceilings for a hatch. It might have a visible latch in which case it's likely to open downwards - don't let it smack you on the head. If there's no latch - it just looks like a panel in the ceiling - it should lift up. With a drop down hatch, if you're lucky, there might be a ladder which will pull down with the hatch, on a cord, or using a pole. Otherwise you'll need a ladder to get up there.

Comment: thx a lot, I am in Vancouver, Canada for the reference.